# Contents of array display as [object HTMLInputElement], which I do not want

Tags: javascript

So this function here is supposed to get which cakes are checked from a form:

```
function whichCakesAreChecked() {
    var cake = document.forms[0];
    var cakesChecked = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < cake.length; i++) {
        if (cake[i].checked) {
            cakesChecked.push(cake[i]);
        }
    }
    return cakesChecked.toString();
}
```

And I have another function which takes the output of whichCakesAreChecked() and pushes it into an array via `giantArray.push(whichCakesAreChecked)`. When I try printing out the array, whichCakesAreChecked() does not return the cakes checked but instead something like `"[object HTMLInputElement],[object HTMLInputElement]"`.

How do I change my code to actually print out the cakes that have been checked?

Comment: It is because you are probably pushing the whole html element to `cakesChecked` so you end up with an array of object and then you are converting those array of objects to string.

Comment: where is watershed array defined. The problem which rishipuri mentioned is there

Comment: Can you share with us all the code please?

Comment: @rishipuri That turned out to be the issue, thanks!

Comment: @bobthebuilder4t5 Didn't my solution help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does something like this help?
Here, instead of putting checkbox element, we can put the checkbox names.
Putting checkbox elements into the array and calling `toString()` results in multiple `[object HTMLInputElement]`as they are objects of type `HTMLInputElement`.

```js
function myfunction() {
  var arr = [];
  var elem1 = document.getElementById('one');
  var elem2 = document.getElementById('two');
  arr.push(elem1.name);
  arr.push(elem2.name);
  console.log(arr.toString());
}
myfunction();
```

```html
<label for='one'>One</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="one" checked="checked" name="one" />
<br/>
<label for='two'>Two</label>
<input type="checkbox" id="two" name="two" />
```